# Flex: Special-casing an item in a list or menu?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I've found it's often useful to special case the first item in a drop-down menu (ie, an instance of Menu).  For example, if I want to pick a color from the list provided by a web service:

```
<mx:PopUpMenuButton id="colorSelelector"
    dataProvider="{colorsService.lastResult}" />
```

I might also want a special-case, which is "enter a new color", allowing the user to enter the RGB values for a new color which isn't in the list.  For example:

```
var newColor = { label: "Enter a new color", rgb: null };
```

Then used with:

```
<mx:PopUpMenuButton id="colorSelelector"
    dataProvider="{colorsService.lastResult}"
    lastOption="{newColor}" />
```

So, apart from changing the list I get back from the service, is there any better way to do this?

(and just a preemptive comment: this is a simplification… I'm not actually trying to make a color-picking-list)

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to the dataProvider, call a function that adds your special case. For instance:

```
<mx:PopUpMenuButton id="colorSelector" 
    dataProvider="{addSpecialCases(colorsService.lastResult)}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, apart from changing the list I get
>   back from the service, is there any
>   better way to do this?

This approach is going to be the cleanest, without extending HTTPService, which would work well (but is really just altering your result ;) ):

```
package
{
    import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

    public class MyHTTPService extends HTTPService
    {
        public var appendToResult:Object;

        public function MyHTTPService(rootURL:String=null, destination:String=null)
        {
            super(rootURL, destination);
        }

        [Bindable("resultForBinding")]
        override public function get lastResult():Object
        {
            //I know what my type is, Array as an example
            var myResult:Array = operation.lastResult;
            myResult.push( this.appendToResult )
            return myResult;
        }
    }
}
```